# How to automatically escape special characters in python but not the alphabetical ones?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm writing with python, and I have a unicode containing special characters, such as double quotes and non english characters.

I want to automatically escape the special characters, but when I use re.escape it escapes all non english characters as well. I'm not sure that's supposed to happen.

Anyway this is problematic because when my python code writes javascript which has this unicode in it, the javascript prints an HTML element that has all these redundant slashes.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the resulting JS code:

```
var myString='\ע\נ\ב\ר'
```

It should be

```
var myString='ענבר'
```

UPDATE:
I used json.dumps(...), but it adds additional quotes before and after. Anyone Knows how to remove that?

Comment: `re.escape` is, as the name says, for escaping strings for use as literal in a regular expression. That's something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using this:

`json.dumps(myString, ensure_ascii=False)`

Works pretty well so far. The added parameter leaves it in unicode.

(but it adds additional quotes before and after parts that have unicode alphabetical characters, so I used `myString = myString[1:-1]`. That's a little ugly, maybe there is a better solution...)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the actual special characters you want to encode. `re.escape` is for avoiding characters special in regular expressions - it doesn't really care about other things.

Perhaps `urllib.quote` is more suitable for your needs (then use something like `decodeURI()` in JS). Or possibly

Answer (score 0):

You can derived your own string class from `str` or `unicode` and override its `__str__()` method which gets called when you print the object. In your custom method you can do anything you wish with regards to escaping characters. One way to do this is to call the base class method and then post-process its output.